# Spring JPA, Lazy Initialization and Dto

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dto

I am trying to fetch user's profile data post login (from login success filter) but I am seeing an exception for Lazy loading the data. Please see the following sample code:

**AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {

        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        UserLoginResponseDto userLoginResponseDto = userService.login(user.getUsername());

        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        response.getWriter().println(gson.toJson(userLoginResponseDto));
        response.getWriter().flush();

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService, TokenService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserLoginResponseDto login(String email) {
        Optional<UserModel> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email);
        UserModel userModel = userOptional.get();
        UserLoginResponseDto userLoginResponseDto = userModel.toUserLoginResponseDto();
        return userLoginResponseDto;
    }
}
```

**UserModel.java**

```
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;


    [A FEW MORE FIELDS]

    @Column(length = 256, nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<RoleModel> roleModels;

    public UserLoginResponseDto toUserLoginResponseDto() {
        return new UserLoginResponseDto().setId(id).setEmail(email).setRoles(roleModels);
    }
}
```

**UserLoginResponseDto.java**

```
public class UserLoginResponseDto {

    private UUID id;
    private String email;
    private List<RoleModel> roles;

}
```

When an object of type UserLoginResponseDto is serialized in `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, I see the following error message -

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: UserModel.roleModels, could not initialize proxy - no Session

**QQ** - How do I resolve this correctly without employing any of the following techniques?

- [ANTIPATTERN] Open-In-View
- [ANTIPATTERN] hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans
- FetchType.EAGER

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're passing *the actual lazy `List`* into `setRoles`, which doesn't trigger the full load. This indicates (immediately) that while you've separated your top-level database class from your top-level DTO, it's a "shallow" separation, which doesn't fully materialize the values. You haven't shown whether `RoleModel` is an entity or an embeddable, and that matters.

So the first step is to copy the items into a non-JPA form. If `RoleModel` embeddable (essentially a POJO), this could be as simple as `setRoles(new ArrayList<>(roles))`. Otherwise, you need a nested DTO, and at that point might consider something like MapStruct.

In either case, though, you're likely to run into the *N+1 problem*. You in fact *do* want an eager fetch *in this case*, and that's what JPA entity graph is for. You can tell Spring Data to fetch the list eagerly only when you want it, and this is a perfect example of when to do that.

Comment: `RoleModel` is an entity as we can see from this mapping: `@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })  private List<RoleModel> roleModels;
`